# Multiple subquery generation with Zend

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I'm trying to reproduce the following SQL using Zend function calls to build the query:

```
SELECT `0`.`id`, `0`.`abbrev` FROM 

  (SELECT  `abbreviations`.`id`, `abbreviations`.`abbrev` 
   FROM  `abbreviations` ,  `keywords` 
   WHERE  `keywords`.`keyword` LIKE  'aug%'
   AND  `keywords`.`abbrev_id` =  `abbreviations`.`id`) `0`

INNER JOIN 

  (SELECT  `abbreviations`.`id` 
   FROM  `abbreviations` ,  `keywords` 
   WHERE  `keywords`.`keyword` LIKE  'foo%'
   AND  `keywords`.`abbrev_id` =  `abbreviations`.`id`) `1` 

ON (`0`.`id` =  `1`.`id`) 

INNER JOIN

  (SELECT  `abbreviations`.`id` 
   FROM  `abbreviations` ,  `keywords` 
   WHERE  `keywords`.`keyword` LIKE  'augment%'
   AND  `keywords`.`abbrev_id` =  `abbreviations`.`id`) `2` 

ON (`0`.`id` = `2`.`id`)

ORDER BY `0`.`abbrev`
```

I know this SQL works as I've tested it. I would have preferred to use SQL "INTERSECT" but since MySQL doesn't support that (and for that matter, I don't know if Zend does either), I had to go with subqueries.

What I'm having difficulty with is doing it the "Zend way" by creating the query with chained function calls, such as $this->getDbTable()->select()->from() etc.

For example, I've been able to successfully create one of the subqueries with:

```
public function selectAbbrevIdsByKeyword($keyword, $abbrevFields) {
    return $this->getDbTable()->select()
    ->from(array('a' => 'abbreviations'), $abbrevFields)
    ->from(array('k' => 'keywords'), 'abbrev_id')
    ->where('`k`.`keyword` LIKE ?', $keyword . '%')
    ->where('`k`.`abbrev_id` = `a`.`id`')
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false);
```

However it all falls apart when I try to combine subqueries into my overall target SQL statement with something like:

```
$all_abbrev_cols = array('id', 'abbrev');
$first_subselect = $this->selectAbbrevIdsByKeyword('foo', $all_abbrev_cols);
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select();
$select->from(array('0' => $first_subselect), $all_abbrev_cols);
$select->join(array("1" => 
    $this->selectAbbrevIdsByKeyword($keywords[1], 
        array('id'))), "`0`.`id` = `1`.`id`");
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
Zend_Debug::dump($select->__toString());
```

By "falls apart", I mean SQL is produced which is just baffling, particularly all the extraneous backticks.

````
string(1006) 
"SELECT ```id``)`.`id`, ```id``)`.`abbrev`, ```id``)`.`description`, ```id``)`.`status`, ```id``)`.`rec_practice`, ```id``)`.`type`, ```id``)`.`category`, `SELECT ``a``.``id``, ``k``.``abbrev_id`` FROM ``abbreviations`` AS ``a``
 INNER JOIN ``keywords`` AS ``k`` WHERE (``k``.``keyword`` LIKE 'aug%') AND (``k``.``abbrev_id`` = ``a``.``id``)_2`.* FROM (SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`abbrev`, `a`.`description`, `a`.`status`, `a`.`rec_practice`, `a`.`type`, `a`.`category`, `k`.`abbrev_id` FROM `abbreviations` AS `a`
 INNER JOIN `keywords` AS `k` WHERE (`k`.`keyword` LIKE 'foo%') AND (`k`.`abbrev_id` = `a`.`id`)) AS ```id``)`
 INNER JOIN (SELECT `a`.`id`, `k`.`abbrev_id` FROM `abbreviations` AS `a`
 INNER JOIN `keywords` AS `k` WHERE (`k`.`keyword` LIKE 'aug%') AND (`k`.`abbrev_id` = `a`.`id`)) AS `SELECT ``a``.``id``, ``k``.``abbrev_id`` FROM ``abbreviations`` AS ``a``
 INNER JOIN ``keywords`` AS ``k`` WHERE (``k``.``keyword`` LIKE 'aug%') AND (``k``.``abbrev_id`` = ``a``.``id``)_2` ON `0`.`id` = `1`.`id`"
````

Is there a way to do this with the "Zend way" of producing the SQL via chained Zend function calls, or should I just give up and say this query is too complex and instead build up the query as a string (using Zend_Db_Expr and/or quoteInto for parameters/quoting)?

Comment: You can do this the 'zend way' - but its almost too much of a headache.  The best hybrid I've seen is that programmers will build each subselect using a zend_db_select() and then get the __toString() version of that... and then create the final zend_db_select using zend_db_expression to enclose all those strings.  By then, you might as well just use standard query().

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ended up doing; I'll post more info below for others' future reference

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing what Aaron described in his comment, just because it was easiest with the code I already had.

I wrote a helper function which used the standard Zend method of building a subquery based on a parameter:

```
public function selectAbbrevIdsByKeyword($keyword, $abbrevFields) {
  return $this->getDbTable()->select()
              ->from(array('a' => 'abbreviations'), $abbrevFields)
              ->from(array('k' => 'keywords'), 'abbrev_id')
              ->where('`k`.`keyword` LIKE ?', $keyword . '%')
              ->where('`k`.`abbrev_id` = `a`.`id`')
              ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
              ->__toString();
}
```

Then I built the query up as a big string, using the subquery helper method, and submitted it all with Zend_Db_Adapter's query() function:

```
$all_abbrev_cols = array('id', 'abbrev', 'description', 'status', 'rec_practice', 'type', 'category'); 
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ';
foreach ($all_abbrev_cols as $col) {
  $sql .= "`0`.`$col`, ";
}
$sql = substr_replace($sql, '', -2); // remove last comma-space
$sql .= " FROM \n\n";

// first subquery is special, has all cols and is "0"
$sql .= '  (';
$sql .= $this->selectAbbrevIdsByKeyword($keywords[0], $all_abbrev_cols);
$sql .= ") `0`\n\n";

// starting on SECOND element (index 1)
for ($i = 1; $i < count($keywords); $i++) {
  $sql .= "INNER JOIN\n\n  (";
  $sql .= $this->selectAbbrevIdsByKeyword($keywords[$i], array('id'));
  $sql .= ") `$i`\n\nON (`0`.`id` = `$i`.`id`)\n\n";
}

$sql .= 'ORDER BY `0`.`status`, `0`.`abbrev`';

$entities = array();
foreach ($this->getDb()->query($sql)->fetchAll() as $row) {
  $entities[] = $this->_populate($row);
}
return $entities;
```

That produced query results matching the SQL statement in my original question.